# object string Coalesce

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, sharepoint-2010

Good day,

Im trying to use coalesce with SPListItem. What i want to accomplish is simple. Check if the object has a value, if true take the SPListItem String and put it into a variable, if false put string.Empty into the variable.

Seems though that Coalesce cannot do that. Can i create an extention method that will accept the SPListItem and do this?
So far i have this:

```
private static string Coalesce(Object historyListItem)
{
    try
    {
        return historyListItem.ToString();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return string.Empty;
    }
}
```

I do not think this is the right way to do this. Any ideas on how i can modify is to comply with "Microsoft best practice"?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "Check if the object has a value"?

Comment: Basically a SPListItem could contain text or not. I want to check if it does have a value

Comment: So what exception are you expecting, and from where? This quesiton is pretty confused atm...

Comment: Like @JonSkeet said ...not very clear ... the only place where I can see the exception thrown, is if `historyListItem` is null. In which case, you could actually use the coalesce `??` option.

Comment: If the problems is null you can do `return historyListItem == null ? string.Empty : historyListItem.ToString();`.

Comment: @Noctis: Or the code within `ToString()` could be throwing an exception, which would be pretty grim...

Comment: @JonSkeet :) ... and what are the changes of that? shall I start coding a try/catch around all my ToString() calls?

Comment: @Noctis: It depends on how badly `ToString` is implemented. And no, of course you shouldn't surround every `ToString` call with a try/catch - I'm just pointing out that there's other information we're missing.

Comment: @JonSkeet Ohhh ... you mean if he overrides the default one ... I was thinking about the default ToString by microsoft :). True, True ...

Comment: @Noctis, She to be exact.. I decided to rather go the route of `return historyListItem == null ? string.Empty : historyListItem.ToString();` This seems to give me the results i wanna achieve. Thanks @Alessandro D'Andria

Comment: Cheers, then add it as an answer, explain why, and hopefully it'll help someone else ... sorry about the s/he... :)

Comment: Thanks no problem :) it happens.. @Alessandro D'Andria can you add it as an answer please so i can flag it as answered

Comment: @KokiPortableNkanyane I added my comment has an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the problems is null you can do:

```
return historyListItem == null ? string.Empty : historyListItem.ToString();
```